# Django datetime task friendly format

Tags: django

How would you format django datetime, so it produces results in task friendly format

```
23 sec remaining
2 hour 14 minutes remaining
4 days
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the [`timeuntil`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil) filter useful.

```
{{ my_datetime|timeuntil:target_date }}
```

The above snippet will return the time remaining until `target_date` is reached.

> **timeuntil**
>
> Similar to `timesince`, except that it
>   measures the time from now until the
>   given date or datetime. For example,
>   if today is 1 June 2006 and
>   conference_date is a date instance
>   holding 29 June 2006, then `{{
>   conference_date|timeuntil }}` will
>   return "4 weeks".
>
> Takes an optional argument that is a
>   variable containing the date to use as
>   the comparison point (instead of now).
>   If `from_date` contains 22 June 2006,
>   then `{{
>   conference_date|timeuntil:from_date }}`
>   will return "1 week".
>
> Comparing offset-naive and
>   offset-aware datetimes will return an
>   empty string.
>
> Minutes is the smallest unit used, and
>   "0 minutes" will be returned for any
>   date that is in the past relative to
>   the comparison point.